# PHP: How to replace multiple $_SESSION array values

Tags: php, session-variables, shopping-cart

First time making a PHP/XML shopping cart and am having trouble with the update cart feature. I have a $quantities array that needs to update the $_SESSION["cart"] values. Right now, the last quantity in the $quantities array is replacing all the $_SESSION["cart"] values, as opposed to the first $quantities value replacing the first $_SESSION["cart"] value, second replacing the second, etc. Below is a simple example showing my problem and the code I'm having trouble with.

```
print_r($SESSION["cart"]);
print_r($quantities);
foreach($quantities as $index=>$quantity)
{
    foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $key=>$value)
    {
        $newcart = str_replace($value, $quantity, $_SESSION["cart"]);
    }
}
print_r($newcart);
```

which results in:

```
Array ( [Pizzas.Tomato & Cheese.Small] => 1 [Homemade Lasagna Ravioli or Manicotti.With Sausage.One Size] => 1 )
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 )
Array ( [Pizzas.Tomato & Cheese.Small] => 4 [Homemade Lasagna Ravioli or Manicotti.With Sausage.One Size] => 4 )
```

How can I get that last array ($newcart) to be

```
Array ( [Pizzas.Tomato & Cheese.Small] => 3 [Homemade Lasagna Ravioli or Manicotti.With Sausage.One Size] => 4 )
```

? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$newcart=array_combine(array_keys($_SESSION['cart']),$quantities);
```